# (-1)^k with random k of either 0 or 1

Tags: swift, random

I want to have something to happen when (-1)^k is 1 and when its -1 -> k is generated randomly.

I tried this but it doesnt work

```
let test:Int32 = -1
let leftOrRight:CGFloat = pow(CGFloat(test),random(min:0,max:1))

func random(min : CGFloat, max : CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    return random() * (max - min) + min
}
```

leftOrRight is always NaN.

Comment: **U** in UInt32 = what? Why does the "error make sense"?

Comment: true i was braindead , i changed it to let test:Double = -1, but now leftOrRight is always NaN

Comment: Make sure the question reflects the (trivially corrected) code.

Comment: What is your desired result?  Do you want `leftOrRight` to be `-1` or `1` with equal probability?  Is `k` an `Int`?

Comment: yes correct, thats what should be in leftOrRight after and I need it as a CGFloat because I set a position of a SpriteNode left or right from the Screen

Comment: k = random(min:0,max:1) so it is a CGFloat

Comment: How about: `let leftOrRight: CGFloat = arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 ? 1 : -1`

Comment: @Beginner what version of Swift are you using?

Comment: looks way better than what i tried thank you

Comment: @Carpsen90 I dont know, i am using Xcode Version 9.4.1, so it will be some version of swift 4 i think

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30835352/2303865

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to generate a `CGFloat` value of `-1.0` or `1.0` with equal probability.  You can do that by generating a value of `0` or `1` (using `arc4random_uniform(2)`) and testing it before assigning the `CGFloat` value:

```
let leftOrRight: CGFloat = arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 ? 1 : -1
```

In **Swift 4.2** (Xcode 10), you could use `Bool.random()` to simplify it:

```
let leftOrRight: CGFloat = Bool.random() ? 1 : -1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Swift **4/4.1** then this should do the trick:

```
let leftOrRight = 2 * (Double(arc4random_uniform(2)) - 0.5)
```

If you are using Swift **4.2**, you could use:

```
let array: [CGFloat] = [-1, 1]
let leftOrRight: CGFloat = array.randomElement()
```

If you want `leftOrRight`to be a random Boolean:

```
let leftOrRight: Bool = Bool.random()
```

For more on what's coming in Swift 4.2 have a look [here](https://learnappmaking.com/random-numbers-swift/).